# Can GPL be implied to a derivative work?

Tags: licensing, open-source, gpl

There are three software projects: A, B and C.

A is published to anyone and is licensed under GPL.

B extends A, is published too, but has no license information or is mistakenly licensed under LGPL. Basically it violates the license of A by not being GPL. Source code of B is still available.

C extends B. Can C be published under GPL? Motivation would be "A is GPL, any derivative must be GPL too, so B is GPL and C can be GPL too".

Comment: What part of B is C extending? If they are all in A already, I see no problem. If C extends parts of B which where *not* in A, things are getting interesting.

Comment: I would name the A, B, C projects and contact the authors of B.

Comment: Also, I believe that you could at least publish C under GPL, since GPL is LGPL compatible. But IANAL

Comment: @Tichodroma, C extends parts of B, but B cannot exist without A :)

Comment: Did the author of C also write (a part of) A? If not, we have no idea what license the authors of A gave to B, so we have no idea if we can build on it?

Comment: @dcorking Let's assume there are three different authors and A was licensed only under GPL.

Comment: Then @gnasher729 is right: "If B released their code under a stricter license than GPL, then B is most likely committing copyright infringement. You can't use B's code under the GPL license. That's often confused: GPL cannot force B to do anything."

Comment: IMHO it's simple and the license of B doesn't matter. By definition C is a derivative work of A, so C *has* to be under the GPL.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First off, B is in violation of the GPL on A. But that's not exactly your concern and is irrelevant to the question here (who knows, maybe B got a LGPL license from A on their code so that it may be released under LGPL?).

The question is "Can you build a GPL piece of software based on LGPL code?"  The answer to this is simply "yes".

The LGPL is less restrictive than the GPL (thus why B is in violation of the license on A unless other provisions were made), but also allows it to be brought back into a GPL project fairly easily.

From the LGPL license:

> 3. Object Code Incorporating Material from Library Header Files.
>      The object code form of an Application may incorporate material from a header file that is part of the Library. You may convey such object code under terms of your choice, provided that, if the incorporated material is not limited to numerical parameters, data structure layouts and accessors, or small macros, inline functions and templates (ten or fewer lines in length), you do both of the following:
>
>    a) Give prominent notice with each copy of the object code that the Library is used in it and that the Library and its use are covered by this License.
>      b) Accompany the object code with a copy of the GNU GPL and this license document.

Its part of the license. You can easily build a GPL software based on LGPL code.

There are some [version differences](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#gpl-compat-matrix) that you'll have to pay attention to to make sure that the code is licensed in the correct way, under the correct version of the GPL.

---

In the event that there is no license information presented, you ***do not have the right*** to extend upon it. B should not have been distributed, but its contributions are ***not*** licensed under an open source license. This may have been an internal project that got published or some other event.

It is not presented under a license that is compatible with extending with the GPL.  Consider the situation that a company, using GPL software internally (acceptable - not a violation), mistakingly made their repo public.

In this case, it is quite possible that the project C is in violation of copyright infringement itself (the material that B added that is not licensed under the GPL as it should not have been distributed in the first place).

One *cannot* force a license on someone else's source. It is either in compliance with the license, or in violation of it.  If it is in violation of it, then as spelled out in the license:

> You may not propagate or modify a covered work except as expressly provided under this License. Any attempt otherwise to propagate or modify it is void, and will automatically terminate your rights under this License (including any patent licenses granted under the third paragraph of section 11).

A violation of the GPL does not mean that the material is under GPL, but rather that it can't be distributed.

Comment: Good answer. Did you consider committing to the [Open Source Stackexchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82234?page=1&phase=commitment&committers=userreputation) proposal?

Comment: Note: This only applies if B is under LGPL; the question also contained "B has no license info" as a possibility, and in that case you can't do anything with B's code.

Comment: @cpast thank you for reminding me of that other condition to how B is distributed. I've written more about if there is no license attached to it.

Comment: Thank you! But who is the author of project B and has the right to decide how to license B? Aren't authors of A somehow involved there?

Comment: @Andrej The only person who has the right to determine how B is to be licensed are the people who wrote B. If A is GPL'ed, they have the option of "do not distribute" or "license as GPL". That it was mistakingly distributed, does not mean that it is licensed as GPL.

Comment: Also, nice catch on "you don't know if B got a different license from the authors of A;" it's possible B isn't violating A's copyright at all, because you don't know B is using A under the GPL (the authors of A can issue as many licenses of as many types as they want, and can e.g. offer it under GPL *and* sell a license for it that lets you use it in proprietary code).

Comment: @cpast yep.  That's a not uncommon approach for the writers to monetize some GPL. One that I'm familiar with is [iText](http://itextpdf.com/pricing) which can be purchased, or used with the AGPL. It would be an interesting question for a lawyer to look at the license that it comes in under and if it could be re-released under a *different* open source license. There's also the possibility that the software was initially released under BSD and then moved to GPL (and you're just looking at the *latest* versions of everything).

Comment: In the case where B's author receives A under GPL license the fact of distribution does not force GPL on B. But are there any licenses that would do this? So a person can publish its software and be sure that anyone will get access to all future published derivatives? And allow anyone to force license on derivatives. (I can start a new question for this one :) )

Comment: @Andrej No copyright license can do that. The only way to force a license to be issued is through copyright *law*; it can only be put in by the legislature. The most you can do with a copyright license is sue someone for monetary damages for violating the license; you can use that to pressure them, but if they stop distribution they've stopped violating the copyright, and you can only make them pay money for the past infringement.

Comment: @Andrej If it helps, remember what a copyright license is. A's authors have certain exclusive rights, including distribution and making derivative works. No one can do that without permission from A's authors. The authors of A give permission to make and distribute derivatives under certain conditions; that's a license. But you can't *force* someone to use a work under a given license; you can only punish them for distributing without having permission to do so.

Comment: @Andrej: you can *attempt*, in your license, to create a "shrink-wrap EULA"-style situation, where if a person does X then they agree to Y. So if you fill in "distribute a derivative work" as X, and "put that work under this license" as Y, instead of "use the software" as X and "accept these terms" as Y, then your license would attempt to force a license as you ask. Whether a court would uphold the term to mean that Y happened, is quite another matter. By saying only legislation can force a license, cpast in effect is asserting that no court would uphold that term even if you wrote it.

Comment: @SteveJessop Actually, that's a good point; a contract comes under different law than a license. As far as I can tell, though, it's unclear whether a) a court would enforce the EULA, especially if the software is released in an open-source manner; b) whether a court would enforce the EULA by requiring specific performance (depends on jurisdiction, in the US and UK you'd normally just get damages). Also, EULAs have other issues on open-source software: someone can just patch out the EULA and users of their derivative aren't bound by the EULA. EULAs have to be accepted before they have power.

Comment: @cpast you can force them to accept the EULA before they download the sources

Comment: @Lohoris And if they then post the source online for others to download? If someone gets the source without seeing the EULA, they are not bound by the EULA (just by copyright). If the EULA requires that anyone posting the source of the project or of a derivative of the project behind an EULA wall, then that applies to any other project the code is added to, making it useless for anyone else to build on (and illegal to combine with GPLed stuff, because you can't distribute GPL stuff under an EULA that restricts further distribution).

Comment: @cpast yes, it would be incompatible with the GPL, but why do you say _"it would be useless for anyone to build on"_. That same thing could be said about the GPL…

Comment: @Lohoris First, as a practical matter, plenty of GPL software exists, while nothing works with this. Second, contracts are not transferable the way licenses are. This is critical to open-source: if I have the software, I can give it to you. An EULA means that you *must* accept the license to even view the source. If you view the source but don't accept the EULA, it doesn't apply. Third, you'd need to accept a separate EULA for every single person who wants to require this stuff; if you and I both write code requiring an EULA, any user must agree to *both* EULAs. It scales **horribly**.

Comment: Fourth, an EULA is much, much, much more legally questionable than the GPL. The GPL imposes no restrictions; any restriction is actually from statutory copyright law (what the GPL does is waive those restrictions in some cases). That's why the GPL works so well -- there isn't such a thing as a "GPL violation," there are just *copyright* violations. With an EULA, you need to get people to agree to restrict themselves; this means you're in the realm of contract law, which is very murky and filled with possible defenses, like that someone didn't agree (you don't need to agree to copyright).

Comment: Thanks for nice comments. The stuff isn't trivial. @cpast But in my current opinion GPL is not doing its job well. The idea (in my understanding) is that open-source software remains open-source forever and free for anyone to use and modify it. But with GPL if author of A dies then B can be published and made proprietary with no chance for community to fix the violation of GPL and get hands on the B's sources (except rewriting B).

Comment: @Andrej: that's one of the reasons serious infrastructure projects that are GPLed make sure that at least part of the software, and preferably as much as possible, has copyright assigned to some kind of organization. That way the death or unavailability of one author doesn't prevent the copyright being used to enforce the license. Or the author of A could choose to leave their software to (e.g.) FSF in their will. So I don't think it's the GPL's fault, just a limitation of licensing law that without the copyright you can't enforce a license.

Comment: If the GPL legally could just define that all derivative works magically are GPL-licensed, then presumably it would. But it can't, so instead it has to work within existing copyright law by restricting what you are permitted to do with derivative works (specifically, by permitting you to distribute them only if they don't impose GPL-incompatible restrictions on the recipients). So yes, if the copyright to A is no longer held by someone willing to enforce those restrictions, then the GPL cannot do its job of restricting non-free activity.

Answer (score 4):

There are copyright holders: There is copyright on the works created by A, there is copyright on the additions by B, and there is copyright on any changes that C made. C must check whether he has permission to use the software on which A and B hold copyrights.

A was licensed under the GPL. I am quite sure that the GPL gives you permission to use A's work under the GPL terms, even if you received them from B who licensed them incorrectly. There may be practical problems: For example, you must be able to provide the source code. If you received the software without source code, then you have no way to publish it under the terms of GPL.

B was licensed under some other license. B *should* have been licensed under the GPL, but wasn't. If B's license give you more rights than the GPL, you don't actually have any of those rights for A's code - B can't give you additional rights to A's code. You can use A's code under GPL terms because A allowed it, and B's additional code under B's license.

If B released their code under a stricter license than GPL, then B is most likely commiting copyright infringement. You can't use B's code under the GPL license. That's often confused: GPL cannot *force* B to do anything. It only gives B the choice: Publish this way, and it is legally fine, or publish another way, and it is illegal. B has the right to do something illegal and suffer the consequences (being sued for copyright infringement). You don't have any rights to B's code that B didn' give you.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, it is possible to extend a GPL library with code that is itself not covered by the GPL license. The snag is that when you distribute the derived work that you created, you must observe all the requirements that the GPL places on you.

In your situation, this means that it is possible to have library A under the GPL and the *new* code in library B under the LGPL. The combined work (library B) is effectively distributed under the GPL license, and can be distributed as such because the LGPL license is compatible with the GPL license (you can use LGPL licenses code in a GPL licensed project).
In that situation, it is perfectly fine to have the *new* code in library C under the GPL, with the resulting work under the GPL as well.

Comment: This only works because LGPLed parts of B can be used with the GPLed A under the GPL. If the new code was under some license conflicting with the GPL (e.g. all rights reserved), you can't assume B as a whole was effectively distributed under the GPL.

Comment: @cpast: You are right, I forgot to mention that the LGPL is compatible with the GPL. If the licenses were incompatible, you would not be allowed to distribute the result.